# How to add path before every cpp in a SET variable? (CMakeLists)

Tags: cmake

I have the following variable in my CMakeLists:

SET(SOURCE s1.cpp s2.cpp ... )

I would like to add a path before each sx.cpp but I don't want to add it by hand like that:

SET(PATH path)
SET(SOURCE {$path}s1.cpp {$path}s2.cpp ... )

Is there a way to add the path without having to copy the variable around?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
FOREACH(SRC ${SOURCE})
  LIST(APPEND SRC2 "${PATH}/${SRC}")
ENDFOREACH()
```

and you have your result in `SRC2`